# Find Nearest rows in SQL

Tags: sql

I have table with 2 records and column name quantity.

```
quantity
2268
22680
```

so,
when my required quantity 2500 then i want to display both 2 records
when my required quantity 2000 then display 1st row.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, SQL tables have no such thing as a "first" row, so you need a column to specify the ordering.

Comment: I guess u don't just have 2 records, explain us in detail what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a cumulative sum.  The ANSI standard method would be:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(quantity) over (order by ?) as cume_quantity
      from t
     ) t
where cume_quantity - quantity <= <your value here>;
```

The `?` is for the column or expression that specifies the ordering of the rows.